# Making a custom UISegmentControl(sort of)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, menu, custom-controls

I've got this mock up:

[image]

As you can see, it's a sort of navigation-menu. It's functionality should be the same as a segmented control, and i am going to change the tableView based on the item active.

What would be the easiest way to implement this?

I have started makin my UIView-subclass, but found out that i had to then make a delegate, watch for tap-events and stuff.
**Is this the best way to do it**? **Should i subclass UISegmentedControl?**

***Any other advice?***

Please, point me in the right direction. I feel confident in Obj-c, but making these kinds of stuff makes my mind goes crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, `UISegmentedControl` seems like a good choice for this, but I don't think it's quite flexible enough to create the effect you're going for here.

Have you considered putting three `UIButton` controls inside a custom view? You can customize the images for each button using `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to get the border style in your mockup. Set the `selected` property of the pressed button to `YES`, and `UIButton` will handle the drawing for you.

You can set up an action method to detect which button was pressed by calling

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(nameOfMethodToHandleButtonPress) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside])]
```

A delegate is just any class that conforms to a protocol you create. So you would create a delegate protocol in your header like this:

```
@class MyControl; // this is a forward reference to your class, as this must come before the class @interface definition in the header file

@protocol MyControlDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)myControl:(MyControl *)control didSelectButton:(int)buttonIndex; // replace this method with whatever makes sense for your control

@end
```

And the delegate is just a property in your `MyControl` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyControlDelegate> delegate; // you use 'assign' instead of 'retain' to prevent retain cycles
```

And in your button press handlers, for example:

```
- (void)methodThatHandlesButtonPress { // this is the method you set up in the first code example with addTarget:action:forCotnrolEvents:
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myControl:didSelectButton:)])
        [self.delegate myControl:self didSelectButton:0]; // replace as appropriate
}
```

Now, you just have to have the view controller that contains your control adopt the protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyControlDelegate> { // etc...
```

And implement the method:

```
- (void)myControl:(MyControl *)control didSelectButton:(int)buttonIndex {
    // handle the button press as appropriate
}
```

Comment: That's what i'm coding right now. But i don't really understand how i'm able to detect which button was pressed, and then implement a delegate to send the selected-item out to the main viewController?

Comment: Seriously. You are the god. If i could vote up hundred times, i would do it. Thank you!